# Should I cut off loose rusty rebar before patching concrete foundation (spalling)?

Tags: repair, concrete, exposed-rebar

I have patched a lot of concrete foundation that is spalling.  I encountered a loose piece of rebar (6'long) that I can try to stick back in the old concrete before I patch over it, or I can cut it out before patching.  Any recommendations?[image]

[image: concrete with loose rebar]

Comment: How much cover would the rebar have if you left it there?

Comment: There would be up to an inch of cover; some portion would be very little cover.  In fact, one section I already repaired (shown in my picture) I cut off 5 feet where it actually would not be covered at all! It's hard to see in the picture (but you can see it on left side), the loose rebar overlaps another piece of rebar by 2 ft.

Comment: Rebar needs to be firmly held be concrete to provide strength. I doubt you will be able to attach/embed it very strongly in the repair concrete so cut it off.

Comment: One of the comments (blacksmith37) said to cut it off. I was favoring cut it off. A Lowes specialist said to cut it off. One random person disagreed and provided extraordinary instructions to attach it securely to new stub-out rebar that I would install (ie. don't cut it off).
So, based on input so far, I am heading outside to cut it off.